# This scope in a simple React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have an issue with, i think, scope when it comes to this.onItemClick in my Filter component.

Getting an error "onItemClick is not defined".

Here's the code for the Filter component.

```
var Filter = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: ''
    };
},
onItemClick(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
},
render() {
    return (
        <div className="filterCloud quarter-section">
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <ul>
              {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue) {
                  return <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>{listValue}</li>;
              })}
              </ul>
        </div>
    )
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `this` for [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback, because now `this` refers to global scope(in browser it is `window`, or `undefined` if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))

```
this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue) {
   return <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>{listValue}</li>;
}, this);
   ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind here

```
var Filter = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: ''
    };
},
onItemClick(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
},
render() {
    return (
        <div className="filterCloud quarter-section">
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <ul>
              {this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue) {
                  return <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>{listValue}</li>;
              }.bind(this))}
              </ul>
        </div>
    )
}});
```

Comment: you don't need use `.bind`, because you can set `this` through
 second argument - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

you should bind `this` to your anonymous function.

Try this:

```
{this.props.filterList.map(function(listValue) {
                  return <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>{listValue}</li>;
              }.bind(this))}
```

or use arrow function (automatically does the job):

```
{this.props.filterList.map( (listValue) => {
       return <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>{listValue}</li>;
   }
)}
```

Comment: you don't need use `.bind`, because you can set `this` through
 second argument - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `babel`, you can use `arrow functions`:

```js
var Filter = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: ''
    };
  },
  onItemClick(event) {
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="filterCloud quarter-section">
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.filterList.map((listValue) =>
            <li onClick={this.onItemClick}>{listValue}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```